# Python API autentication

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, curl, token, webapi

I want to login by web API. The flowing code is working properly if I use curl at command line and I get a TOKEN.

```
LOGIN_RESULT=$(curl "$URL/application/login" --data-binary '{"login":"user","password":"password"}'           )

# extract the token from the server's reponse
# (Requires the json parser "jq" , sudo apt install jq)
TOKEN=$(jq .token <<< $LOGIN_RESULT |tr -d '"')

I would like to write a Python script which do same action, but I received always error.
I need a TOKEN but I always run a error.
```

---

Python:

```
payload = {'login':'spn','password':'password'}
response = requests.post('http://...login/', data=payload)

print(response)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

---

<Response [401]>
401
{"message": "Restricted area, token is not valid.", "code": "ERROR_LOGIN", "parameters": ""}